# TypeError: 'float' object does not support item assignment & Pandas Slicing

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas-groupby

A TypeError appears within a For Loop.  The For Loop's key, yrmon, is assigned to a column "YEAR" (avg_temp["YEAR"]).  yrmon contains a six character string, and the "YEAR" column contains an 8 digit value.  What's odd, is that the code is pulled from a lesson; I simply retyped it.  I'm unsure of what I mistyped.

Lesson and repository can be found at:
https://geo-python.github.io/site/notebooks/L6/advanced-data-processing-with-pandas.html
https://github.com/Geo-Python-2020/Exercise-6
I'd recommend focusing between "String Slicing" & "For-loops and grouped objects".  I contacted the instructors by email and LinkedIn.

I've looked at two TypeError postings.  Because of my novice understanding, I wasn't able to determine their relevance.

Thanks for your collective time!  Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data/1091402.txt', skiprows=[1], delim_whitespace=True, na_values='******')

monthly_data = None

data["DT_YM_SL"] = data["DATE"].astype(str)
data["DT_YM_SL"] = data["DT_YM_SL"].str.slice(start=0, stop=6)

grouped = data.groupby(["DT_YM_SL"])

for yrmon, group in grouped:
    avg_temp = group['TAVG'].mean()
    avg_temp["YEAR"] = yrmon
    monthly_data = monthly_data.append(avg_temp, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
avg_temp = group['TAVG'].mean()
```

avg_temp is the mean of 'TAVG' column, which is float because *mean()* method returns a float number, and equals to ~29.48 on first iteration of FOR loop. So, this line of code:

```
avg_temp["YEAR"] = yrmon
```

becomes

```
29.48["YEAR"] = '195201'
```

and this is not possible in Python.

Comment: Thank you, Imran.  Should I consider how to convert avg_temp from float to integer?

Comment: Converting avg_temp from float to integer will be useless.

Comment: Very well, Imran.  What needs to change in the code, please?